# How to step into a set of chained methods with gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have a bunch of methods chained together, for example:

```
obj->getA()->getB()->doSomething()->doSomethingElse();
```

If I set a breakpoint on that line and I start stepping into it, gdb walks into the first method (`getA()`).

How can I step directly into `doSomething()` instead?

Comment: set a breakpoint inside doSomething

Comment: GDB allows you to specify breakpoint commands. They can even control the state of GDB itself.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky seems sensible. However, what if `doSomething` belongs to some external and obscure code you have little knowledge of?

Comment: In this case rewrite your code and split the calls into 2 lines auto b = obj->getA()->getB(); b->doSomething()->doSomethingElse();